# Factoring polynomials over finite fields using Maple and Maxima

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, factoring, maple, maxima-software

Can you factor polynomials over certain finite fields using Maple or Maxima, and if so, how?

Comment: What's the purpose of having a Maple category if all questions about Maple get flagged as off topic?? How could a Maple question possibly be more mathematical than this one??

Comment: @CarlLove I agree. If Maple is off topic, why do we have a maple (and maxima) tag? And where else should we ask questions about mathematical software?

Comment: You guys put it on hold because it is apparently *not about mathematics, within the scope defined in the help center* May I cite the help center? *What to ask here: (...) Software that mathematicians use (except Mathematica, which has its own Stack Exchange site).*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Maple,  you can use Factor and mod, e.g. for factoring over $GF(7)$

> Factor(x^2 + 3 x + 3) mod 7;

$$(x+6)(x+4)$$

For $GF(p^k)$, represented using a root of a polynomial of degree $k$ irreducible over $GF(p)$:

> alias(alpha = RootOf(x^3 + 2));
>
> Factor(x^4 + x^2 + 2*x + 2, alpha) mod 7;

$$(5 \alpha^2 + x + 1)(x+4)(6 \alpha^2 + x + 1)(3 \alpha^2 + x + 1)$$